# Wordpress & Learndash - Course Redirection Filter via PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm very new to PHP programming, and I'm completely stumped by what is likely a very easy piece of code.

I have built a website using Wordpress and Learndash LMS to sell online courses. One of the courses has two quizzes; One in the middle of the course, and one at the end of the course.

Due to the limitations of Learndash, I am not able to add the quiz after a lesson. Or if I do, there is a "Mark Complete" button that essentially would allow a student to skip the quiz, which I do not want them to do.

The solution I found was a php filter provided by Learndash:

```
add_filter("learndash_completion_redirect", function($link, $post_id) {

//You can change the link here

//$post_id is ID of the lesson/quiz from where the user is being redirected from. $link is the link to which the user is redirected from.

return $link;
}, 5, 2);
```

However, I have no idea how to make this filter work.

Where do I put the links, but also what do I write as code to make it work?

For example, when a student completes Lesson 10 on the course and the link is "http://course.com/lesson10", I want this filter to take the student to Quiz 1 "http://course.com/quiz1"

Again I'm very new to PHP programming, so if I haven't been completely clear on my explanation I apologize and will add any additional information if needed.

Assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This add_filter goes into the functions.php file in your active theme directory.

Your code should determine from the post_id where you are and where you want to go to and return the new pade URL in $link.